# Unable to find template Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, twig

When I updated from Symfony 3.4 to Symfony 4 and displayed the system with a browser, the following error appeared.
Changing the views directory is a lot of work and I don't want to do it as much as possible. Is there any good way?
**Error Code**

```
Unable to find template "AhiSpAdminBundle:Security:login.html.twig" (looked into: /home/vagrant/Symfony/src/Sp/AppBundle/Resources/views, /home/vagrant/Symfony/templates, /home/vagrant/Symfony/vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Resources/views/Form).
```

**Code**
framework.yaml

```yaml
framework:
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
```

twig.yaml

```yaml
twig:
    paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/src/App/AppBundle/Resources/views']
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
```

SecurityController.php

```php
    /**
     * @Route("/login")
     * @Template("SpAppBundle:Security:login.html.twig")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
```

**Version**
Symfony 4.0
PHP 7.3
twig/twig 2.14
twig/templating 4.0
sensio/framework-extra-bundle 5.2.4

Comment: Hi did you try to clear the cache: bin/console cache:clear ?

Comment: Symfony has moved away from the colon notation for specifying twig templates i.e. SpAppBundle:Security:login.html.twig should be something like @SpApp/Security/login.html.twig.  bin/console debug:twig will confirm the correct twig namespace to use.  Of course converting your template paths is also quite a bit of work.  You might try adding a twig path.  Been awhile since I have done that.  Consider updating your question with a list of twig namespaces generated by debug:twig

Comment: @GrenierJ Thanks for your comment. Certainly I handed it over.

Comment: @Cerad Thanks for your comment. Thanks to the easy-to-understand explanation, I was able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the path to twig.yaml and the accompanying changes worked.

twig.yaml

```yaml
twig:
    paths:
        '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Sp/AppBundle/Resources/views': SpApp
```

Controller

```
    /**
     * @Route("/login")
     * @Template("@SpApp/Security/login.html.twig")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
```

~.html.twig

```
{% extends '@SpApp/layout.html.twig' %}
```